# How to install and use NPM packages in appcelerator alloy

Tags: node.js, npm, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

Does anyone know the how to install and use npm packages in Alloy projects?

I am trying to use a sharepoint module, https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharepointconnector.

I have installed it via 'npm install sharepointconnector' in various directories, moved into /Resources, /app/lib directories, but still not working. Most cases I get the 'sharepointconnector not found in ...' error.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appcelerator does not support npm packages to the alloy or classic app. Appcelerator only supports as a [module](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Module_Development_Guide), [Titanium Module Concepts](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Module_Concepts). Actually, that npm packages is created based on the nodeJS app. So, you can use that packages in your nodeJS app then create your custom API. Alloy or classic App support any web API.

Hope you got the point.

Comment: if I understand correctly, I would need to create a module using the npm packages. Then, import the newly created module?

Comment: NPM packages are now supported (in certain cases) as of SDK 6.0.0.  [Read more here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_SDK_6.0.0.GA_Release_Note-section-src-48432896_TitaniumSDK6.0.0.GAReleaseNote-NodeJSsupport)

Answer (score 0):

In my own understanding, you can use any npm package that is not browser dependent.

Position your self in the folder `myApplication/app/lib`

(If you haven't created the lib folder yet, please do it inside the `app` folder)

Then install your npm package, lets take the `validator` package for example:

```
npm install validator
```

The trick in using the lib is to require it properly, you can't just call

```
var validator = require('validator');
```

if you go inside the lib folder you 'll find a node_modules/validator created with all its dependencies, inside you will find the file `validator.js` and that is the file i needed to require.

So what was left to do is correct the requiring call :

```
var validator = require("node_modules/validator/validator");
validator.isEmail("foo@bar.com") // returns true => happy days :)
```

Hope this helped

Comment: Like you have mentioned, only npm packages that don't have dependancy on other js frameworks would work.

Comment: It seems that there is a module called sharepoint Connector but just the lite version, see if it helps.

search for it in the market place at:
https://marketplace.appcelerator.com